# При изменении размера экрана до 489px появляется белая полоса справа

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь адаптацией сайта под мобильные устройства, при изменении ширины экрана до 489px справа появляется белая полоса и внизу бегунок прокрутки, как будто у какого-то элемента либо margin установлен либо ширина больше чем 489. Но я проверил и не заметил такого. Может вы поможете разобраться в чем проблема. Вот, закачал сайт на бесплатный хостинг http://grishanov.zzz.com.ua/[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Открываю в хроме панель отладки и начинаю удалять блоки со страницы. Когда прокрутка пропадает, перегружаю страницу и копаю вглубь блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прокрутка исчезнет, если убрать вот эти строки в стилях:

```
media-queries.css:87
@media (max-width: 979px)
#bg12 ul {
    /* width: 450px; */
    /* left: 12px; */
Ъ
```